# Broad cast receiver for Incoming Gmails

Tags: android, notifications, gmail, broadcastreceiver, listener

What I need to do is to create an app that produces custom notification sounds for each incoming Gmail depending upon the sender. So I need to be notified when a new mail arrives and also get the email_id or Name of the sender of the email. 
Few of the solutions that came to my mind were,

1) Gmail labels API - But it doesn't provide info about the emails inside or notifies.
2) Using content resolver with READ_GMAIL permission - I think Gmail has stopped access on newer Gmail versions.
3) Reading notification bar or a notification listener - Android wont allow to read notification bar.

Is there any other workarounds which can solve this?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure, hope this will help you out

1. You need to register a content observer (not broadcast receiver)

`contentResolver.registerContentObserver(Uri.parse("content://gmail- ls"), true, _gmailObserver);`

`_gmailObserver` is your own `ContentObserver` object.

1. `ContentObserver.onChange` is going to be called every time something changes in Gmail.

Here you get all conversations like so:

```
Cursor conversations = _contetResolver.query(Uri.parse("content://gmail-ls/conversations/"  + YourEmailAddress, null, null, null, null);
```

And the actual conversation messages will be:

```
Cursor messages = _contetResolver.query(Uri .parse("content://gmail-ls/conversations/" + YourEmailAddress + "/"  + String.valueOf(conversationId) + "/messages"), null, null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, at least by any documented and supported means.